# Error in Unity Project integration with VSCode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, omnisharp, unity3d-mirror

I'm trying to develop my first game using Unity(2020.1.9f version).Due to low configuration I'm using VSCode as editor instead of default Visual Studio.But every time I open my project in VSCode it shows error in importing
Mirror(package for multiplayer functionality).I think I have imported it correctly because Project is running well in Unity.But because of this error I'm not able to use Intellisense for Mirror package in VSCode.
This is how error looks:[image]

Here is the Omnisharp log while opening project in VSCode.

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 11/3/2020, 12:34:06 AM
    Target: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\CardGame.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0\.omnisharp\1.37.4-beta.10\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 2796

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0\.omnisharp\1.37.4-beta.10\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0\.omnisharp\1.37.4-beta.10\.msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0\.omnisharp\1.37.4-beta.10\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            CscToolPath = c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0\.omnisharp\1.37.4-beta.10\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0\.omnisharp\1.37.4-beta.10\.msbuild
            MSBuildToolsPath = c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.0\.omnisharp\1.37.4-beta.10\.msbuild\Current\Bin
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\CardGame.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\SimpleWebTransport.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Telepathy.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Cloud.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Components.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.GUI.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.Pong.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Authenticators.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.example.RigidbodyPhysics.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Weaver.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Editor.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.CompilerSymbols.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\SimpleWebTransport.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame' on host 7448.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\SimpleWebTransport.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\SimpleWebTransport.csproj'
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to add project to workspace: 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\SimpleWebTransport.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.OmniSharpWorkspace
        Miscellaneous file: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\obj\Debug\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs added to workspace
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Telepathy.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Telepathy.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Telepathy.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Cloud.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Cloud.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Cloud.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Components.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Components.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Components.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.GUI.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.GUI.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.GUI.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.Pong.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.Pong.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Examples.Cloud.Pong.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Authenticators.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Authenticators.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Authenticators.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.example.RigidbodyPhysics.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.example.RigidbodyPhysics.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.example.RigidbodyPhysics.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Weaver.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Weaver.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Weaver.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Editor.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Editor.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.Editor.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.CompilerSymbols.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.CompilerSymbols.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Mirror.CompilerSymbols.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Successfully loaded project file 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Adding project 'c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj'
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Could not locate project in workspace: c:\Users\MANISH KUMAR\CardGame\SimpleWebTransport.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Telepathy
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Cloud
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Components
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Examples
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Examples.Cloud.GUI
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Examples.Cloud.Pong
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Assembly-CSharp
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Authenticators
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.example.RigidbodyPhysics
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Weaver
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.Editor
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Mirror.CompilerSymbols
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Update project: Assembly-CSharp-Editor
```

Previously same problem occured in importing **UnityEngine.UI** but it resolved when I regenerated csproj files.But this current import is not resolving .I've tried everything form downgrading C# extension to reinstall Unity but to no avail.Please Help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To fix this issue, you should go to unity package manager and update Visual Studio Code Editor to version 1.2.3.

Tested with Unity 2019.4.1f1 LTS